# Concurrency when saving new comments

Tags: database, comments

Taking a look at function `comment_save()` from comment.module, I can't understand how Drupal avoids duplicates when getting `$max` value on this statement:

```
$max = db_query('SELECT MAX(thread) FROM {comment} WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid' => $comment->nid))->fetchField();
```

Even the query is in a transaction, a select query is non-blocking and two users posting a comment simultaenously can get same thread value.

Moreover, table comments allows duplicates on thread field so no exception will be fired in case of duplicates.